# Golang SSH-Server: How to handle file transfer with scp?

Tags: ssh, go, scp

I have written a small SSH-Server in golang with the crypto/ssh package.

It supports returning an interactive shell and immediate command execution.

Here is a minimal example of the server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    c := &ssh.ServerConfig{
        PasswordCallback: func(c ssh.ConnMetadata, pass []byte) (*ssh.Permissions, error) {
            if c.User() == "foo" && string(pass) == "bar" {
                return nil, nil
            }
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("password rejected for %q", c.User())
        },
    }

    keyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("key")
    key, _ := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(keyBytes)
    c.AddHostKey(key)

    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:2200")
    for {
        tcpConn, _ := listener.Accept()
        _, chans, reqs, _ := ssh.NewServerConn(tcpConn, c)
        go ssh.DiscardRequests(reqs)
        go handleChannels(chans)
    }
}

func handleChannels(chans <-chan ssh.NewChannel) {
    for newChannel := range chans {
        go handleChannel(newChannel)
    }
}

func handleChannel(newChannel ssh.NewChannel) {
    channel, requests, _ := newChannel.Accept()
    for req := range requests {
        switch req.Type {
        case "shell":
            go handleShell(channel)
        case "exec":
            go handleExec(channel, req)
        }
    }
}

func handleShell(c ssh.Channel) {}
func handleExec(c ssh.Channel, r *ssh.Request) {
    cmdString, args, _ := parseCommand(r.Payload)
    log.Printf("exec: %s\n", cmdString)
    for i := range args {
        log.Printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, args[i])
    }
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdString, args...)
    cmd.Run()
}

func parseCommand(b []byte) (string, []string, error) {
    cmdString := strings.TrimSpace(string(b))
    cmdArray := strings.Split(cmdString, " ")

    cmd := strings.Trim(cmdArray[0], " ")
    args := cmdArray[1:]

    return cmd, args, nil
}
```

If I run the server and execute scp as follows:

```
scp -P 2200 test.file foo@localhost:~/
```

the handleExec function is called.

The output of the cmdString shows:

```
2015/11/22 17:49:14 exec: scp
2015/11/22 17:49:14 arg 0: -t
2015/11/22 17:49:14 arg 1: ~/
```

But how can I implement the handleExec function to actually save the file/dir I passed via scp?

Comment: First, start by properly executing the scp command, either by passing it to a shell, or splitting the arguments yourself (can't remember which ssh does)

Comment: Ok, i parsed the cmd string and the scp command will be executed with the given arguments. But i have no clue at all how the actual file is passed to scp. Is it in the r.Payload or will it be transmitted over the ssh.Channel? I can't even find the -t option in the scp man page.

Comment: The command is in the payload, you already parsed that in your code. The files are transferred over the channel, and handled by the scp command you exec. (As for `-t`, the scp command isn't part of the ssh spec. The openssh scp source is probably the best resource for all options)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still struggle to solve the problem how to pass the file/dir from the ssh.Channel to the scp command i exec.

Comment: You don't have a file or directory to pass to the scp command, that's sent from the client scp (scp technically has nothing to do with ssh, it just knows how to invoke ssh and use it as a pipe). All you need to do is connect the client's scp instance with the stdin and stdout of the exec'ed command.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the problem of executing scp and custom commands over my ssh server and as it is undocumented how to do this I pieced together some code from the tests in crypto.ssh (https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/session.go and https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/session_test.go) It works with OpenSSH and the crypto.ssh client. You can for instance call session.Run() on your client and handle e.g. scp or custom commands with it.

```
type exitStatusMsg struct {
    Status uint32
}

// RFC 4254 Section 6.5.
type execMsg struct {
    Command string
}

go func(in <-chan *ssh.Request, channel ssh.Channel) {
        for req := range in {
            if req.Type == "exec" {
                var msg execMsg
                if err := ssh.Unmarshal(req.Payload, &msg); err != nil {
                    log.Printf("error parsing ssh execMsg: %s\n", err)
                    req.Reply(false, nil)
                    return
                }
                go func(msg execMsg, ch ssh.Channel) {
                    // ch can be used as a ReadWriteCloser if there should be interactivity
                    runYourCommand(msg.Command, ch)
                    ex := exitStatusMsg{
                        Status: 0,
                    }
                    // return the status code
                    if _, err := ch.SendRequest("exit-status", false, ssh.Marshal(&ex)); err != nil {
                        log.Printf("unable to send status: %v", err)
                    }
                    ch.Close()
                }(msg, channel)
                req.Reply(true, nil) // tell the other end that we can run the request
            } else {
                req.Reply(req.Type == "shell", nil)
            }
        }
    }(requests, channel)
```

You need to replace runYourCommand with whatever function then executes your command and set the exit code to whatever your command/process returns.